# implementing CRM on Sharepoint 365

Tags: crm

I need to implement a basic CRM system. Any advice on doing it in Sharpoint 365, but without using Dynamics?

Any experience on using an APP or Sharepoint feature to run basic CRM functions will help. I started witn Contacts, but that is too basic.

The main feature I am looking at is the tracking of issues related to a specific user and the possibility to store any interaction with him.

Thanks.

Comment: Mike, your question is very broad and any answer would be primarily based on opinion. Could you rephrase it so that a more specific answer could be given? Please see the FAQ if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Helo my friend, you can create one .net application with access your SP 365 APP, for this get this framework:

https://ssoh.codeplex.com/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SennitSharepointHelper/

Comment: if you need any help for using this framework please call me. enjoy!

Comment: You should make it very clear that your are behind this product..